# React: How to access to several combos or elements of a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I'm using react with bootstrap.

I've got several combos with the same list of values and the same value selected in the same page. What I want is If I modify one of them then all the others change it's value selected to the value selected by me.

The structure of my code is:

```
<FormGroup>

<Form.Control as="select" 
    id = "season-1"
    style = {{marginTop: 10 + "px"}}
    value = {this.state.seasons.description}
    onChange = {this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.seasons_options}
</Form.Control>  
<Form.Control as="select" 
    id = "season-1"
    style = {{marginTop: 10 + "px"}}
    value = {this.state.seasons.description}
    onChange = {this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.seasons_options}
</Form.Control>  
<Form.Control as="select" 
    id = "season-1"
    style = {{marginTop: 10 + "px"}}
    value = {this.state.seasons.description}
    onChange = {this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.seasons_options}
</Form.Control>  
<Form.Control as="select" 
    id = "season-1"
    style = {{marginTop: 10 + "px"}}
    value = {this.state.seasons.description}
    onChange = {this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.seasons_options}
</Form.Control>  
<Form.Control as="select" 
    id = "season-1"
    style = {{marginTop: 10 + "px"}}
    value = {this.state.seasons.description}
    onChange = {this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.seasons_options}
</Form.Control>  

</FormGroup>
```

Then, I would like to modify someone of them and then modify the value selected of all others.

How can I do that?

Comment: weird ... just use `handleChange` to set value of `this.state.seasons.description`?

Comment: Yes, with handleChange I can know the value of the combo but then I need to know how to access to the other combos and modify their default values with the value selected in the combo. For example, I modify combo-1, with handleChange I know the new value and then I want to update the default value of the other combos with the new default value of combo-1

Comment: all selects are the same value dependants, just modify value, all should be rerendered with new value

Comment: Thank you so much @xadm for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: you should know that after very basic react tutorials :]

Comment: You are truth @xadm. I did it before but I have been a mistake passing all the values to "value" attribute instead of only to pass the value selected. That was my mistake :S